# Adding text to a data move between different cells

Tags: vba, excel

So I currently have this code;

```
Function ISMERGED(CellAddress As Range) As Boolean
  ISMERGED = CellAddress.MergeCells
End Function

Sub Demerge()
Dim CurrentCell As Range
    For Each CurrentCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If ISMERGED(CurrentCell) Then CurrentCell.UnMerge
    Next
End Sub

Sub Txfer()
Dim x As Long
Dim TestRow As Range

Call Demerge

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .UsedRange.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Formula = "Test Name"
        .Cells(1, 2).Formula = "Test Description"
        .Cells(1, 3).Formula = "Step Name"
        .Cells(1, 4).Formula = "Test Step"
        .Cells(1, 5).Formula = "Expected Result"
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For x = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(x, 2).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value
                .Cells(x, 3).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value
                .Cells(x, 4).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value
                .Cells(x, 5).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 5).Value
                'add in further columns
            Else
                .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4).Formula = .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 4).Value & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value
                .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5).Formula = .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5).Value & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 5).Value
                'concatenate existing content of target cell with data from current source row
            End If

        Next x
    End With
    'now to tidy up the blanks...
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).Activate
    Do
        If Application.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow) = 0 Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Row < 2
    Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

I want to add an "if" statement that if there is anything in the Test Data (This is the data in "Cells(x, 2).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value") field of the source sheet, I would like to have the test description field contain: “Test Data: “ followed by the text from the source. If the source cell is empty, I would like the Description field to also be empty.

Basically I just want to add the words "Test Data" before the text that is being moved if their is text present in the original cell

Comment: Are you asking how to use the `&` operator to concatenate two text strings together?

Comment: Honestly mate i'm not sure - would that be the best way of doing it? Add an "&" operator between my string "Cells(x, 2).Formula = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value" and the new string I want to add?

I'm basically a complete novice trying to learn the ropes.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: I felt I should clarify - in worksheet1 column 2 there's sometimes data in there that I'm moving across to column 4 on worksheet 2. If there is data there I want it to be prefaced with "test data" in worksheet 2.

Comment: I settled on;

                .Cells(x, 2).Formula = IIf(Len(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value)) = 0, "", "Test Data: " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value)